# How to make a web part fully trusted

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part

I'm developing a web part as a sandoxed solution that uses a DLL (deployed in the cash). When I run the web part from VS, I got the following exception on the first use of this DLL. Any directions on how to fix this ?

```
System.MethodAccessException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233072
  Message=Attempt by security transparent method 'VisualWebPartProject2.VisualWebPart1.LoadData(System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView, System.String)' to access security critical method 'IPeople.Direct.DirectConnection..ctor(System.String)' failed.

Assembly 'VisualWebPartProject2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0c7a664b53b4bf31' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.
  Source=VisualWebPartProject2
  StackTrace:
       at VisualWebPartProject2.VisualWebPart1.LoadData(GridView gridView, String connectionString)
       at VisualWebPartProject2.VisualWebPart1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1):

The assembly in a sandbox solution does not get deployed to the GAC and it does not run in the regular worker process (w3wp). It instead runs in a separate worker process called the user code process.

Sandbox solutions are limited to using a subset of the server object model and the are restricted from accessing anything outside of SharePoint (external web services, databases, the file system, etc).

If you want a sandbox solution to access an external resource you need to build a full-trust proxy which must be deployed as a farm solution.

[Sandboxed Solutions in Partnership with Full-Trust Proxies in SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg622616%28v=office.14%29.aspx)